# Convert custom single string into JSON in c# and construct final json based upon condition

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a string in the following format

```cs
string data = "key1:value;key2:value2;key3:value3;create_date:2020-05-15 14:18";
```

I tried to convert this into the following JSON format and not able to achieve

```cs
{ "key1":"value", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3", "create_date":"2020-05-15 14:18" }
```

and would like to construct the final json based on condition (to save only json data that is 'IsActive' - coming from a configuration table from database)

Final JSON that will be stored in database

```cs
{ "key1":"value", "create_date":"2020-05-15 14:18" }
```

Comment: `I tried to convert this` I don't think there is question in your statement

Comment: @YegorAndrosov  i have updated the question. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily convert your string into `Dictionary<string, string>` and create a JSON from it with help of `JObject`

```cs
string data = "key1:value;key2:value2;key3:value3;create_date:2020-05-15 14:18";
var dict = data.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split(':')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
var json = JObject.FromObject(dict).ToString();
```

Unnecessary keys can be easily removed using `dict.Remove("key1");`

Answer (score 1):

Please check following code for converting your string to json and removing keys before putting it in database

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = "key1:value;key2:value2;key3:value3;create_date:2020-05-15 14:18";

    str = ConvertToJson(str);
    str = RemoveKeysFromJson(str, new string[] { "key1", "key2" });
}

static string ConvertToJson(string str)
{
    var splittedArr = str.Split(';')
        .Select(x => 
            Regex.Replace(x, "^(.*?):(.*)$", x =>
            {
                return $"\"{x.Groups[1].Value}\":\"{x.Groups[2].Value}\"";
            })
        );

    var json = "{" + string.Join(",", splittedArr) + "}";

    return json;
}

static string RemoveKeysFromJson(string json, IEnumerable<string> keys)
{
    var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

    foreach (var key in keys)
    {
        jobject.Remove(key);
    }

    return jobject.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I am getting `Unexpected character '$'`  in this `return $"\"{x.Groups[1].Value}\":\"{x.Groups[2].Value}\"";` .